# Please explain about unmap

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx

I am studying directx12 and I think there is a problem with understanding map and unmap, so I ask a question

```
hr = constantBufferUploadHeap[i]->Map(0, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&cbColorMultiplierGPUAddress[i]));
    constantBufferUploadHeap[i]->Unmap(0, &readRange);
    memcpy(cbColorMultiplierGPUAddress[i], &cbColorMultiplierData, sizeof(cbColorMultiplierData));
```

If I use map and call unmap right away, can't memcpy be able to work normally? But seeing it work. Please explain about unmap

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. The CPU pointer is invalidated after Unmap and everything can happen with UB (one of the scenarios is it will work). Have you tried running it in release mode?

Comment: I get the same result in release mode. I understand that map is unlock and unmap is lock, but I think I need to change my mind through this problem.